# how do I know where GS cookie is?

Tags: cookies, stack

On modern linux, we can apply a `stack smashing protection` to a gcc-compiled binary, an stack cookie from that protection is saved in GS:[0x14].
In this case I am wondering how to get an exact base address of GS.